# How to Change Column Field Format in Microsoft Access with SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I need to be able to write a script to create a table in Microsoft Access, and I am running into a problem.  I need a long integer field (longer than `LONG`), so I have to use `DECIMAL`.  The problem I am running into is it is defaulting the **Format** to scientific notation.  I need it to stay as a normal integer value.

Here is my script:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
   MY_GUID GUID CONSTRAINT MY_CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY,
   MY_NAME VARCHAR,
   CREATOR VARCHAR,
   MILLI_CREATED DECIMAL (13, 0)
);
```

The `MILLI_CREATED` field defaults to *General Number* **Format**, which then displays the value in scientific notation, like this:  `1.444255960009E+12`

How can I set the **Format** of the table during `CREATE` or with an `ALTER` or even at `INSERT` if that is what I have to do?

Comment: To be clear, I know how to alter it through the **Access** GUI; that is not a solution to my problem.

Comment: Looking for this http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/access-vba-create-table-and-format-fields/5c243510-2aa6-40cf-8ccd-c794d0e8fb97?auth=1 ?

Comment: I'd suggest recording a macro and doing it in the GUI and seeing what the macro gives you.

Comment: You cannot manipulate the `Format` property of a field using DDL. You'll need to use ACE/Jet DAO for that. See the link from @BitAccesser above.

Comment: @JohnBingham you can't record macros in Access

Comment: If you're numbers are that big, are they really numbers means for computation/math? Would you be better off storing your numbers as text and converting to a number in the off chance you do need to do some math on them?

Comment: @BitAccesser Thanks for the link, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

Comment: @Brad At this point, I think your suggestion is my best option to move forward.  I will, unfortunately, need to use these for some computations, but I know how to convert the string, so at least then this is no longer a blocker for me.